# SQL backup file size and post restoration table size conflict in MSSQL server

Tags: sql-server, database-backups

I did a backup restoration of db.  The size of the backup file was 204+ GB, but when I restored it and ran a query to find the total Used data space it was showing 706+ GB.  Unable to tally the math and feeling lost.  Can someone explain and clear my doubt on what has happened?

TIA

Comment: SQL Server backups support compression, so... compression?

Comment: Two possible reasons: the backup may have been compressed, and the backup doesn't store empty pages in the database (but the restore does recreate them). You did say it was the count of used data space, so that's probably not it, but still.

Answer (score 0):

Backup file size is not indicative of the database size on disk once restored.

As was mentioned in the comments, backups can be compressed which may be contributing to the difference.

Also, database & log files in SQL Server usually contain some free space. The free space is important because it can a) allow data to be inserted into the database without incurring the performance overhead of growing the database file size each time a transaction occurs & b) allow large transactions to run without growing the log file as it will likely already be big enough to deal with the largest regular transaction that occurs in the database. So, don't [unnecessarily shrink](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2017/12/whats-bad-shrinking-databases-dbcc-shrinkdatabase/) your database & log files to reduce free space as the files will just end up growing back into it again!

There's more information in the blog post above, including how to query the used vs free space in the database & log files.

Hope that helps.